# Require a field if other field has value

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have 3 field which is `bank_name`, `account_name` and `account_number`. How can I  require other two fields if one of them has value? my validation for now looks like this:

```
validate = [
    'account_name' => ['sometimes','nullable', 'max:50'],
    'bank_name' => ['sometimes','nullable', 'max:50'],
    'account_number' => ['sometimes','nullable', 'max:50'],
];
```

How can I possibly attain this one?

Comment: I guess you would use the conditional validation rules
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `required_with`:

```
$validate = [
    'account_name' => ['sometimes','nullable', 'max:50', 'required_with:bank_name,account_number'],
    'bank_name' => ['sometimes','nullable', 'max:50', 'required_with:account_name,account_number'],
    'account_number' => ['sometimes','nullable', 'max:50', 'required_with:account_name,bank_name'],
];
```

With the rules above, when one of the 3 fields has a value, the two other ones would be required.

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-with

Comment: Thanks for this one, this is almost the same of what I've done, but mine was individual.